# Cant access file from a vm(machine_Ip/folder/file) in glue script

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer

file = '//<ip>/Users/Billing1642.csv'

bucket_name='trd'

client=boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

transfer = S3Transfer(client)

transfer.upload_file(file,bucket_name,'test.csv')
```

Comment: What does that mean? can you give more info? It is too brief and codes only.

Comment: @Lamanus is there a way aws glue can access a file present in a vm(aws vm), i am accesing it like <machine Ip>/folder/file.... in my local python script(spyder) i am able to access the file with the same <machine Ip>/folder/file way,but the same i cant do with aws glue